# What would `\stackrel` be if you were to write it out in full as an entire English phrase?

Tags: latex3, fractions, english

Most **LaTeX** commands have a full-English counter-part.

Some Examples of what I am looking for are shown in this posting.

What is the full English equivalent of `\stackrel`?

```python
d = {
     'approx'             : 'approximately' , 
     'cdots'              : 'centered dots' , 
     'cong'               : 'congruent' , 
     'ddot'               : 'double diagonal dot' , 
     'dfrac'              : 'display fraction' ,  
     'equiv'              : 'equivalent to' , 
     'exists'             : 'there exists' , 
     'frac'               : 'fraction' , 
     'ge'                 : 'greater than or equal to' , 
     'genfrac'            : 'generalized fraction' , 
     'iff'                : 'if and only if' , 
     'iiint'              : 'integral integral integral' , 
     'iint'               : 'integral integral' , 
     'infty'              : 'infinity' , 
     'lbrace'             : 'left brace' , 
     'le'                 : 'less than or equal to' , 
     'lhd'                : 'left lazy head' , 
     'lim'                : 'limit' , 
     'lnot'               : 'logical not' , 
     'lt'                 : 'less than' , 
     'mathbb'             : 'mathematics black board bold' , 
     'mp'                 : 'minus plus' , 
     'mu'                 : 'greek letter mu' , 
     'notin'              : 'not element of or inside of' , 
     'prod'               : 'product' , 
     'quad'               : 'spazio quadratone' , 
     'rangle'             : 'rightangle' , 
     'rceil'              : 'rightceiling' , 
     'simeq'              : 'similar or equal' , 
     'spadesuit'          : 'spadesuitsymbol' , 
     'sqrt'               : 'square root' , 
     'subseteq'           : 'subset or equal' , 
     'subsetneq'          : 'subset not equal' , 
     'sum'                : 'summation' , 
     'varepsilon'         : 'variable epsilon' , 
     'varliminf'          : 'variable limit infimum' , 
     'varlimsup'          : 'variable limit supremum' , 
     'varnothing'         : 'variable nothing' , 
     'vdash'              : 'vertical dash' , 
     'vdots'              : 'vertical dots' , 
}
```

## What is an English phrase for `\stackrel` without any letters deleted?

Comment: stacked relation?

Comment: delety lazy from `'lhd'                : 'left lazy head' ,`  it is lasy (with an s) and that is the font not the character

Comment: why quad in Italian? variable  should be variant

Comment: "stick these two things on top of eash other"

Answer (score 3):

As Clara suggested in her comment, `\stackrel` is short for stacked relation (relation being the “part of speech” of the symbol which determines its spacing).

Incidentally, in your list, in the various `\var`*something* commands, the `var` is short for “variant,” not “variable.”